# Rounding the duration of two date values

Tags: python, date, rounding

I have two `date` values in Python which Im trying to get a rounded duration from.

For example: 01-01-2000 to 12-31-2099 is really "100 years", not "99 years".

I have an example, in Java, but Im not sure how to port this to Python speak:

```
round(endDateEpochInMilliseconds -startDateEpochInMilliseconds /(365.25 * 24 * 3600 * 1000))
```

Im sure something similar is doable in Python.

Comment: I have not experience in Python at all, but I'm curious. What you expect if you have start=04-05-2000, end=10-11-2010? What kind of result? Upvote for interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import datetime

date1 = datetime.date(2000,1,1)
date2 = datetime.date(2099, 12, 31)

delta = date2-date1

print round(delta.days/365.25,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You defently must put `endDateEpochInMilliseconds -startDateEpochInMilliseconds` into brackets!

```
round( (endDateEpochInMilliseconds -startDateEpochInMilliseconds) /(365.25 * 24 * 3600 * 1000))
```

Comment: So what you're saying is this snippet could also run as Python code but with the additional brackets? In python I do not have the ``endDateEpochInMilliseconds`` and ``startDateEpochInMilliseconds`` variables available, So i will need to convert my date objects into epoch milliseconds as part 2 to solving this problem. --Am I thinking correctly on this?

Comment: Flowpoke: no I do not saying anything about phyon, but general Math rules (/ before +) work for (most) programming languages in the same way. -- Your statement would devide only startDateEpochInMilliseconds by (365.25 * 24 * 3600 * 1000) and then subtract this term from endDateEpochInMilliseconds. And this is defently wrong.